# Service fabric actor interfaces

Tags: azure-service-fabric, stateful-actor-service

Is it possible to have an actor containing just properties?

I want to create an actor which will be used to just set and get the properties. For example:
I have an interface like,

```
public interface IData1 : IActor
{
    string Classification { get; set; }
    List<string> Tokens { get; set; }
}
```

I am trying to create an actor proxy object using the below code:

```
var proxy = ActorProxy.Create<IData1>(ActorId.NewId(), "fabric:/Item");
```

I am getting an error saying:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors.dll.Additional information: Method 'get_Classification' of actor interface 'Item.IData1' does not return Task or Task<>. The actor interface methods must be async and must return either Task or Task<>.

Answer (score 3):

Actors are by definition only allowed to pass messages to each other. This can only be done through public asynchronous methods exposed in their actor interface.

If you would like to expose properties of an actors state to another actor or client then you must create explicit asynchronous get/set methods like this.

```
public interface IMyActor : IActor{
    Task<int> GetMyProperty();
    Task SetMyProperty(int value);
}

public class MyActor : StatefulActor<MyActor.ActorState>, IMyActor{

    // This class represents the actors state
    internal sealed class ActorState{
        public int MyProperty {get; set;}
    }

    protected override Task OnActivateAsync()
    {
        State = new ActorState();
        return base.OnActivateAsync();
    }

    public Task<int> GetMyProperty()
    {
        return Task.FromResult(State.MyProperty);
    }

    public Task SetMyProperty(int value)
    {
        State.MyProperty = value;
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Declaring `ActorState` within the actor implementation and marking it `sealed` and `internal` enforces the idea that only this actor is allowed to access that specific state.